# Emails aren't sent

Tags: emails

I have Drupal Open Social distribution running in Compute Engine on Google Cloud. Compute Engine is essencially a virtual machine, very similar to Amazon EC2.

I have installed the SMTP Authentication module, and am using a google email address to send email, but none of the test emails are working.

Here are the configuration choices for the SMTP Authentication Module:
`Turn this module on or off: on`
`SMTP server: smtp.gmail.com`
`SMTP port: 465`
`Use encrypted protocol: Use SSL`
`Username: The Gmail address`
`Password: The Gmail password`
`E-mail from address: The Gmail address`
`E-mail from name: Default value`
`E-mail address to send a test e-mail to: Second Gmail address`

When clicking `Save configuration` to send the email, Drupal returns the following error message:
`Unable to send email. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists.`

How can virtual machine and Drupal be configured to send email?

Comment: I believe the E-mail from address needs to be from your domain name and not Gmail. Ex: `support@yourdomain.com` the same domain you have set in `/admin/config/system/site-information`

Comment: Using an individual GMail account as web email relay is going to be problematic ; it's likely to be flagged as spamming (since a human user won't be using the account). Use an email service provider (e.g. SendGrid, Mailgun, etc.) that will provide you a SMTP configuration that you can use for your Drupal setup.

Answer (score 1):

Google will be blocked your application, check this note:

> If you are using a program that Google does not consider secure, your
>   usage will be blocked unless you enable less secure applications (a
>   security setting that Google does not recommend). For more information
>   see this link to determine the best approach for your mail client or
>   application

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-google-s-smtp-server